# Incorrect Json Deserialization for Subsequent Operations

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unrealscript

I am using FJsonObjectConverter for json deserialization. The result for the first deserialization is correct, but I get an incorrect result for subsequent operations. Maybe I have encountered a situation that belongs to the nature of C++ that I am not familiar with. I am sharing the code and debug results. How do you think I can fix the problem? Thanks.

Debug Result :

As you can see in the json data the “character” property is null but the debugger shows it as previous deserialized data.

[image: debug result]

Code :

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "InJson", CustomThunk,
    meta = (CustomStructureParam = "StructToFill", DisplayName = "JsonStringToStruct"))
static bool JsonStringToStruct(const FString& JsonString, UStruct*& StructToFill);

DECLARE_FUNCTION(execJsonStringToStruct)
{
    P_GET_PROPERTY_REF(FStrProperty, JsonString);

    Stack.Step(Stack.Object, nullptr);
    const FStructProperty* StructProperty = CastField<FStructProperty>(Stack.MostRecentProperty);
    void* StructPtr = Stack.MostRecentPropertyAddress;
    
    P_FINISH;

    UStruct* StructDefinition = StructProperty->Struct;
    bool bSuccess;

    P_NATIVE_BEGIN

        bSuccess = Inner_JsonStringToStruct(JsonString, StructDefinition, StructPtr);

    P_NATIVE_END

    *static_cast<bool*>(RESULT_PARAM) = bSuccess;
}

static bool Inner_JsonStringToStruct(const FString& JsonString, UStruct* StructDefinition, void* StructPtr)
{
    TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> JsonObject;
    const TSharedRef<TJsonReader<>> JsonReader = TJsonReaderFactory<>::Create(JsonString);
    if (!FJsonSerializer::Deserialize(JsonReader, JsonObject) || !JsonObject.IsValid())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!FJsonObjectConverter::JsonObjectToUStruct(JsonObject.ToSharedRef(), StructDefinition, StructPtr, 0, 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```